# Returning std::string from method non-deterministic behavior?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a method that reads a file and returns its contents as a `std::string`. I use the returned `std::string` to compile an OpenGL program. The linking fails (Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.) in some cases due to one or both of the shader parts (read file contents) being `NULL`.

- If I debug my code step by step everything is fine.
- If I print the file contents the linking seems to fail less often.

Why is it behaving differently, where's my mistake?

The `cout` at the end always prints the correct file contents:

```
std::string read_file(const char* filePath) {
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream stream(filePath, std::ios::in);
    if (stream.is_open()) {
        std::string line = "";
        while(getline(stream, line)) {
            content += "\n" + line;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "read_file " << content << "end read_file" << std::endl; // always prints the correct content

    return content; // makes a copy, don't like that, unless RVO?..
}
```

The `fragmentSource` and or the `vertextSource` are sometimes empty:

```
    GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    const char* fragmentSource = tools::read_file(_fragmentShaderPath).c_str();
    std::cout << "vertext shader source: " << std::endl << fragmentSource; // empty sometimes
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);
    CheckCompilation(fragmentShaderID);

    const char* vertexSource = tools::read_file(_vertexShaderPath).c_str();
    std::cout << "vertext shader source: " << std::endl << vertexSource; // empty sometimes
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    CheckCompilation(vertexShaderID);

    GLuint programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programId);

    GLint result = GL_FALSE;
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    if (infoLogLength > 0) { // this fails sometimes, corresponding to either vertexSource or fragmentSource being empty
        std::vector<char> infoLog(infoLogLength + 1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, infoLogLength, NULL, &infoLog[0]);
        std::cout << &infoLog[0] << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to access an object that has bee destroyed resulting in undefined behavior. I suggest you brush up on storage duration and object lifetime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace

```
const char* fragmentSource = tools::read_file(_fragmentShaderPath).c_str();
```

with

```
std::string fragmentSourceStr = tools::read_file(_fragmentShaderPath);
const char* fragmentSource = fragmentSourceStr.c_str();
```

and the same thing for the `vertexSource`.

The issue is that the string you return is a temporary, so it is destroyed after you initialize `fragmentSource` with a pointer to its data, which makes `fragmentSource` point to an already destructed storage.

Comment: fragmentSource does not need to be a pointer to chars. It can remain as a string

Comment: @RichardHodges: it has to be a pointer to char because `glShaderSource` gets a pointer to an array of pointers to chars, so you must take an address of a pointer to char, so there must be a pointer to char variable. Of course we can change `framentSource` to be an `std::string`, but then we'll need to introduce another variable and refactor some code...

Comment: You can take the address at the point of the call with `std::addressof(fragmentSource[0])`. Then you never have to worry about pointer lifetime.

Comment: @RichardHodges: no, that expression is of type `const char*`, but we need `const char *const *`.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd prefer to deal only in c++ types until we actually touch the openGL C api.

So first I'd create a lightweight proxy function in the `tools` namespace:

```
namespace tools {

    auto shaderSource(GLuint shaderId, const std::string& source)
    {
        auto ptr = std::addressof(source[0]);
        return glShaderSource(shaderId, 1, std::addressof(ptr), nullptr);
    }

}
```

Then replace the use of the raw pointer altogether:

```
auto fragmentSource = tools::read_file(_fragmentShaderPath);
std::cout << "vertext shader source: " << std::endl << fragmentSource; // empty sometimes
tools::shaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragmentSource);
```